# Euclidean Algorithm Appears Incorrect in $F_2[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, polynomials

I've been thinking about the polynomials $x^{14} + x^{12} + x^9 + x^7 + x^5 + x^2 + 1$ and $x^8 + x^6 + x^4$, both in $F_2[x]$

Factoring the polynomials, I see that they both have a factor of ($x^2 + x + 1$), yet the Euclidean Algorithm appears to show that they are coprime.

$x^{14} + x^{12} + x^9 + x^7 + x^5 + x^2 + 1 = (x^8 + x^6 + x^4) \cdot (x^6 + x + 1) + (x^6 + x^4 + x + 1)$

$x^8 + x^6 + x^4 = (x^6 + x^4 + x^2 + 1)x^2 + x^2$

$x^6 + x^4 + x^2 + 1 = (x^2)(x^4+x^2+1) + 1$

GCD = 1

I highly doubt I disproved the Euclidean Algorithm, so any thoughts as to where I went wrong? I've been scratching my head for quite a bit.

Wolfram Alpha also lists the GCD as 1, but how can this be possible if I can find a common factor of both polynomials?

Answer (score 3):

The first line of your Euclidean algorithm is incorrect.
\begin{align*}
(x^8 + x^6 + x^4) \cdot (x^6 + x + 1) + (x^6 + x^4 + x + 1) &= (x^{14} + x^{12} + x^{10}) + (x^9 + x^7 + x^5) + (x^8 + x^6 + x^4)\\
&\qquad + (x^6 + x^4 + x + 1)\\
&= x^{14} + x^{12} + \color{red}{x^{10}} + x^9 + \color{red}{x^8} +  x^7 + x^5 + \color{red}{x} + 1.
\end{align*}

They do both have a factor of $x^2 + x + 1$:
\begin{align*}
x^{14} + x^{12} + x^9 + x^7 + x^5 + x^2 + 1 &= (x^2 + x + 1)(x^{12} + x^{11} + x^{10} + x^8 + x^6 + x^4 + x^2 + x + 1)\\
x^8 + x^6 + x^4 &= (x^2 + x + 1)(x^6 + x^5 + x^4).
\end{align*}

The Euclidean algorithm should actually give:
\begin{align*}
x^{14} + x^{12} + x^9 + x^7 + x^5 + x^2 + 1 &= (x^8 + x^6 + x^4)(x^6 + x^2 + x + 1) + (x^4 + x^2 + 1)\\
x^8 + x^6 + x^4 &= (x^4 + x^2 + 1)(x^4) + 0 = (x^2 + x + 1)^2 (x^4).
\end{align*}